# how to connect azure database in sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

[image]I am trying to connect a database created in ***Azure*** but an error:

Cannot open server '' requested by the login. Client with IP address 'x.x.x.x' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40615)

is showing up

I have added my **IP address**  in firewall settings of the **database** created in **azure**

should i put client IP address in server name of sql server

can anyone help me please.

Comment: Check your IP address with the IP address in the "Client with IP address 'x.x.x.x' ..." message. If your firewall settings actually has that IP address added there's something wrong. However, I think there might be a difference or, like @martin-brandl said, you forgot to press 'Save'.

Comment: should my ip and the client ip be the same??

Comment: You have added the internal IP addresses. You should add your public IP address, since that is the one used to access the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the internal IP addresses. Which are used for internal communication.

You should add your public IP address, since that is the one used over the internet to access the server.

Comment: thank you sir actually i did not know that there was 2 types of ip

Answer (score 0):

Yes, adding your IP address to the firewall settings of the database is the right way to solve it. You probably forgot to save it:

[image]

See also [Manage firewall rules using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#manage-firewall-rules-using-the-azure-portal)

Comment: Just click on the Add client IP button and then on the Save button and you will be fine.

Comment: i have added my ip as the client ip but the error is still there

Comment: No, you added your internal ip, not your internet facing IP. You only have to click two buttons, read my last comment...